# how to have a split window appear below NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

i usually keep a todo list in a file within my project folder.
Is there a way to have that file always appear in a split window below NerdTree ?

I have a key binding for NERDTreeToggle and it be great to have that todo list appear at the same time.

If not possible how can i bind a key to toggle on/off a file (like NERDTreeToggle) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
:nnoremap $YOUR_KEY_SEQUENCE :NERDTree <Bar> :belowright split $YOUR_TODO_FILE<CR>
```

Comment: Hi, a little "buggy" when I open and close several times, but works fine enough. Thanks !